# Poe souls in Zelda: Twilight Princess

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

Where are all of the Poe souls located in the Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess?

Comment: Collecting them all is very annoying because: a) they only come out at night (except in dungeons) but the game gives you no way to change from day to night (like OoT's "Sun's Song"); and b) the game doesn't indicate in any way if you've gotten all the Poe souls in a given area (like OoT did with Skulltulas).

Comment: It's not that bad. You can collect pretty much every out-in-the-open Poe in just 2 night cycles. It stays night for quite some time in TP, so if you effficiently warp around, you can get most of them in just 2 runs. You can ignore the ones in caves and in dungeons since they're always there. I guess the most annoying one is the one on the hill just before the Yetis' mansion since you have to do the snowboarding first, so you'll want to do this ASAP. Wouldn't want to see the morning light before you get there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a lot of lists online. Here are some samples:

- [A simple textual guide](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/750/750298p1.html)
- [A more detailed list](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess/Poe_Souls)
- And finally, a **[list with screenshots!](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/poe-souls-guide)**